# Use Influxdb client in python - Error : 'InfluxDBClient' object has no attribute 'create_database'/' get_list_database '

Tags: python, database, dataframe, influxdb, influxdb-python

I just started using the `influxdb` client in python. I'm probably doing something wrong but I can't figure it out yet.

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient, DataFrameClient  
client=InfluxDBClient(host="localhost",port="8086", username='root')
client.create_database("TEST")
```

I get the following errors:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8086): Max  retries exceeded with url: /query?q=CREATE+DATABASE+%22TEST%22 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000013E5DD0A8C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong ? Also is there a command line that I can use to know what's my `token/url` or what's the `token/url` of a remote host I would like to access.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are making a mistake while importing.
InfluxDBClient should be imported from influxdb.
like:

`from influxdb import InfluxDBClient`

also, constructor `InfluxDBClient()` takes no argument named `url` and `token`.
as per the doc, the constructor is:

```
InfluxDBClient(host='mydomain.com', port=8086, username='myuser', password='mypass', ssl=True, verify_ssl=True)
```

so your code should be like this:

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient, DataFrameClient  
 
client=InfluxDBClient(host="localhost",port="8086", username='root')
client.create_database("TEST")
client.get_list_database()
```

Comment: Hi @fayez, thanks for the answer. I made some changes but now I have a new error

Comment: I will edit my answer to show you the new error @fayez

Comment: did you install influxdb?? also do tell me your operating system @thephoenix

Comment: nevermind, thanks :)   I had to run influxd.exe before running the code for it to work

Comment: its okay! thats what I was about to suggest you!

Comment: This answer is no longer correct per the official 2.0 documentation: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python